# How can I move a load of zone records from a web based system to text based one?

Tags: domain, subdomain, bind, domain-transferring

I have a few domains with Dreamhost where I have set a load of records using their web based domain name system, and I've like to move them to another provider that lets me enter info directly as a text file for their name server, bind 9 to use. (If you're interested, I'm moving them to Gandi.net).

Previously when I used a cpanel based system to do something similar, there was a tool that let me simply enter a domain name, and any available domains were automagically entered into a system, saving me typing it myself (and bringing down sites with silly typos in the process).

What open source tool can I use to query a domain for all the relevant subdomains and records and list them in a format like a zone file, that I can use with other name servers?

Comment: Is it possible to get Dreamhost to allow external axfr requests?

Comment: I don't know what axfr requests are, but it can't hurt to ask them. Will update when I hear from Dreamhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this question comes up a lot.  I answered a similar question in:

[how to request/acquire all records from a DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/117964/how-to-request-acquire-all-records-from-a-dns)

Chances are, Dreamhost is not going to want you to do a zone transfer (axfr) against their production system.  You might be better off asking them for a copy of the zone file.