# List all targets that are available on someones third party DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to request/acquire all records from a DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/117964/how-to-request-acquire-all-records-from-a-dns)

I want to configure my DNS server the same as this third party DNS server for a given domain. It is temporary. We are going to end up taking the whole thing over. I want to see if there are any other subdomains like mail.domain.com

I understand that it is possible that for this given server I will not be able to do a list, but if they permit it I want to. How do I do it?

Comment: Can't you just ask for their zone file if you're going to take it over?

Comment: Chopper3: The existing webmaster is not tech savvy and the existing DNS server administrator is Microsoft. I am asking this question because I run into this question often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dig -t axfr example.com @ns.example.com
```

where example.com is the zone to list, and ns.example.com is the server to ask for the zone.  you are right to note that it is possible (even likely) that the server won't allow this, but if it does, that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the other party to allow "zone transfers" (AXFR) to your server, and configure your server to act as a slave of the other party's zone. This should create a complete copy of the master zone on your server.

Eventually, when the time comes to "take the whole thing over", you can easily convert your server into the master for the zone.